# In place mpi_reduce crashes with OpenMPI

Tags: fortran, mpi

Whenever I try to call `mpi_reduce` with `mpi_in_place` as the send buffer it crashes. A trawl of google reveals this to be have been a problem on Mac OS for OMPI 1.3.3 - but I'm on CentOS with OMPI 1.6.3 (with gfortran 4.4.6).

The following program crashes:

```
PROGRAM reduce

  USE mpi

  IMPLICIT NONE

  REAL, DIMENSION(2, 3) :: buffer, gbuffer

  INTEGER :: ierr, me_world
  INTEGER :: buf_shape(2), counts

  CALL mpi_init(ierr)
  CALL mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, me_world, ierr)

  buffer = 1.
  IF (me_world .EQ. 0) PRINT*, "buffer: ", buffer

  buf_shape = SHAPE(buffer)
  counts = buf_shape(1)*buf_shape(2)

  CALL mpi_reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, buffer, counts, mpi_real, mpi_sum, 0, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
  IF (me_world .EQ. 0) PRINT*, "buffer: ", buffer

  CALL mpi_finalize(ierr)

END PROGRAM reduce
```

The MPI error is:

```
MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
```

which is not very helpful.

Am I missing something as to how `mpi_reduce` should be called? Does this work with other compilers/MPI implementations?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing a very important part of how the in-place reduction operation works in MPI (see the bolded text):

> When the communicator is an intracommunicator, you can perform a reduce operation in-place (the output buffer is used as the input buffer). Use the variable `MPI_IN_PLACE` as the value of the **root process** *sendbuf*. In this case, the input data is taken at the root from the receive buffer, where it will be replaced by the output data.

The other processes still have to supply their local buffers as *sendbuf*, not `MPI_IN_PLACE`:

```
IF (me_world == 0) THEN
  CALL mpi_reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, buffer, counts, MPI_REAL, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
ELSE
  CALL mpi_reduce(buffer, buffer, counts, MPI_REAL, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
END IF
```

You can safely pass `buffer` as both *sendbuf* and *recvbuf* in non-root processes since `MPI_REDUCE` does not write to *recvbuf* in those processes.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I misinterpreted that `MPI_IN_PLACE` documentation as I thought that collective communications had to be called by all processes with exactly the same arguments.

Comment: Oops, are you really sure? Just looked into my production code and I have many instances of the wrong use and I have not encountered a problem so far.

Comment: @VladimirF, there are some collective operations where `MPI_IN_PLACE` has to be specified as send buffer by all ranks, e.g., `MPI_ALLTOALL` or `MPI_ALLREDUCE`. The standard lists the proper use for each operation separately.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, you are right! They are mostly Allreduce and the few instances of Reduce were treated correctly.